# effective way to get the integer sequence A181392 from oeis

Tags: combinatorics, sequences-and-series, number-theory, oeis

the [sequence A181392](http://oeis.org/A181392) are perfect squares and any digit in the sequence says 
"I am part of an integer in which you'll find d digits "d"" (see [A108571](http://oeis.org/A108571), How can we call them? "digit-valid"?)

How to get all these number in sequence A108571?
This is maybe (hopefully) more a theoretical problem instead of using brute-force.
I know two approaches:

1. compute sequence A108571 and check if the number is a perfect square ([use this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/295579/fastest-way-to-determine-if-an-integers-square-root-is-an-integer))
2. test every perfect square if it has the correct "format"

The first one seems to be very slow (there are many numbers in A108571= *multinom.coeff. (45,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1)*). Of course we can create a suffixset containing the last 5 digits numbers of any squares, and put digits before the suffix such that the number is in sequence A108571, permute the all digits except the last 5 digits and test whether it is a perfect square.

The second approach has the advantage that there are "only" $\sqrt{999999999888888887777777666666555554444333221}$ numbers to test.

Are there some theorems I can use? Hensel's lemma gives me a statement about the three last digits of every odd square. So it would be more effective to use store the last 5 digits and start from there.

Is there another tricky theorem or statement I can use?

Comment: There is a link to "source of generating exe", but unfortunately it is dead.

Comment: this was my program which use a simple bruteforce checking all squares.

Comment: One slight speedup: The digit sum of any A108571 number is the sum of some of the numbers $1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81$ and at the same time determines $n\bmod 9$, which must be one of $0,1,4,7$. This rules out (only) half of all digit selections.

Comment: Does the line "*current* rsults" imply I could still get merits by completing the sequemce? :)

Comment: @zyx If I am not mistaken, you have [created the oeis tag](http://math.stackexchange.com/posts/391727/revisions). It is [discussed on meta](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/12485/tag-cleanup-2014/16773#16773) whether this tag is needed. So I thought it might be a good idea to let you know about this.

Comment: @MartinSleziak, thanks.   I only now see your comment (was off the site for months) and don't remember anything about the creation of the tag, assuming that I was the one to do it. But one argument in favor of the tag, is that the concept of "question that references a specific item in OEIS" is a precise subset of sequences-series, that occurs from time to time, and has (seq)fans, but it is not possible to unite these questions except with a tag since the A number is not known in advance (and the question doesn't always write *OEIS* vs Online Encyc... vs Sloane/sequence database).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define a string of nonzero digits to be *$n$-consistent* if when read in base 10, for all $1 \leq d \leq 9$ it has at most $d$ digits equal to $d$ and is congruent to a square mod $10^n$.

Build a tree whose root is the empty string and whose edges represent extensions of a $k$-consistent number to a $(k+1)$-consistent number, recording square integers (in A181392) as they appear.  The tree can be built depth-first and fully explored branches deleted. It is useful to keep track of the powers of $2$ and $5$ dividing each number and maybe the part prime to $10$, and probably also to have computed the nontrivial 2-adic square roots of 1 to mod $2^{45}$ precision.

Some thought may be needed on how to do the mod $10^k$ liftings using the base 10 representation without recomputing in base $2$ and $5$.

Comment: Where exactly do you prune the search space? Hensel lifting lemma states that an odd perfect root must be a square mod 10 (and thus a square mod 2 and a square mod 5). But this only gives a necessary condition what the last three digits have to be?